# Fancybox: window gets cut off at smaller screen sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design, fancybox

I've modified a template that had Fancybox already installed and functioning; I'm having problems with my gallery windows being too big on smaller screens. Currently I have a large image and then a decent block of text below. After modifying the code in the 'main.js' file, I can get the window to fit inside a browser window on a non-Retina Macbook Pro and larger screens, but on a Macbook Air 11" the window gets cut off on the bottom (I know it's about pixels and not screen size, I just don't have the numbers on hand). It's not an issue on a phone because I can scroll the window up with a finger.

One solution would be to enable scrolling inside the windows, but if that is possible then I haven't been able to make it work. Maybe they should be iframes and not gallery windows? If so I would need advice on how to implement that (the template did not come with any iframe examples beyond links to videos).

Here's the site: [Weirdsmobile](http://www.weirdsmobile.net/new/brushed)

Click on any of the tiles in the "Projects" section to see a Fancybox window.

Here is all the javascript code; I got advice to add the **fitToView: false** and **maxWidth: "95%"** because the window initially did not fit on a phone screen. I then added
**maxHeight: "60%"** to try and shrink it to fit, otherwise the full window is too large; but on smaller screens that % is still too high.

```
BRUSHED.fancyBox = function(){
if($('.fancybox').length > 0 || $('.fancybox-media').length > 0 || $('.fancybox-various').length > 0){

    $(".fancybox").fancybox({               
            fitToView: false, // so we can get all the length of the title
         maxWidth: "95%", // will make it responsive; adjust to your needs
           maxHeight: "60%",
           padding : 0,
            beforeShow: function () {
                this.title = $(this.element).attr('title');
                this.title = '<h4>' + this.title + '</h4>' + '<p>' + $(this.element).parent().find('img').attr('alt') + '</p>';
            },
            helpers : {
                title : { type: 'inside' },
            }
        });

    $('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        helpers : {
            media : {}
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: The link isn't working. Try to share your code at jsfiddle.net